# C - Getting a string from an int

Tags: c

I have a list of all strings of a given length in the format

e.g length 3

```
000
100
200
.
.
900
A00
B00
.
.
Z00
a00
b00
.
.
z00
010
.
.
.
zzz
```

I am trying to write `valueof(int pos, int len)`  which accepts a position int as parameter and prints the String at that position (e.g `valueof(1,3)` prints `000` and `valueof(109,3)` prints `k10`

This is what I tried and it is not working:

```
void valueof(int pos,int len)
{   

    int i=0;
    char arry[62] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
        'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
        'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char * string = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        string[i]='0';
    }
    string[len]='\0';
    i=0;
    while(pos >= 62)
    {
        string[i]=arry[(pos%62)-1];
        i++;
        pos/=62;
    }
    string[i]=arry[pos];

    printf("%s\n",string);
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? For example, if we call `valueOf(109, 3)` what currently is reported?

Comment: Read about [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) & [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) and perhaps (on Linux) [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'm not sure that's helpful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, `pos % 62` returns a number between `[0, 61]`. So when you do `(pos%62)-1`, you get a number between `[-1, 60]`. Which you likely don't want.

You should probably rewrite this line:

```
string[i]=arry[(pos%62)-1];
```

as:

```
string[i] = arry[pos % 62];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a test harness.   I would add some bounds checking to the input otherwise you can overrun the array.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void valueof(int pos,int len)
...

   int main (int argc, char **argv) {
     valueof(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]));
   }
```

To compile gcc vo.c -o vo

```
./vo 1 3
000
./vo 109 3
k10
```